# Drupal 7: Filter nodes with a date range arround an exposed date

Tags: php, drupal, view, drupal-7, drupal-views

My issue is somewhat opposite of the common "List nodes within a date range".

So, I have an `Event` content type, with fields `start_date` and `end_date`. They show when the event starts, and when the event ends. Now I need to be able to select a date and fetch all events for which `start_date < selected_date` and `end_date > selected_date`.

The selected date should be an exposed filter to all users, or any other way that makes it possible to be fetcher from the URL.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea:

- Make two exposed filters (one for start date and the other one for end date)
- Hide the other one
- Populate both when user enters something in the first one

This should work if you aren't using AJAX for filtering.

Comment: This is exactly how I did it. Too bad there's no more beautiful way.